# Qt: Is it OK to use QString as a member in exception class

Tags: qt, exception, segmentation-fault, qstring, copy-on-write

I am developing a custom exception, where I'd need a QString member. Something like:

```
class MyException
{
private:
    const QString fDescription;

public:
    MyException(QString desc);
};

MyException::MyException(QString desc) : fDescription(desc)
{}
```

When I try to use it:

```
if (isErrorEncountered)
{
    MyException e(QString("Descriptive message here..."));
    throw e;
}
```

I get a segmentation fault.
The symptoms are similar as described here:
[Qt QString cloning Segmentation Fault](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1861964/qt-qstring-cloning-segmentation-fault)

The SIGSEGV originates from `QBasicAtomicInt::ref`, coming from `QString::QString(const QString &other)`.

It seems to me as if there is an attempt to copy an invalid QString within a copy constructor. It is my understanding, that the QString keeps a pointer to its content as long as there is a valid reference to it. If a copy of MyException instance is being made, is it not true that the temporary stack instance has not left the scope and the copy should succeed?

When I implement `MyException` without a QString member, everything work well.

Comment: Why doesn't `std::string`cut it?

Comment: Is `value` a global object or a typo in your sample exception? Are you certain that the exception is for that QString? Why doesn't your exception constructor take a `const&`?

Comment: I had the same problem, it's something to do with the implicit sharing mechanism of `QString` - though I never did get to the bottom of exactly why. @Evgeni Yes, so would `char*`; but that is nothing to do with the question.

Comment: Have you come up with a minimal example of your program which merely throws the error as written above (patching up the `fDescription(value)` to read `fDescription(desc)`), and then catches it and outputs with `qDebug()`?  Such a minimal case works fine for me.  Follow the process here: http://sscce.org/

Comment: @mat Thanks for warning about the typo. I'll also try with the const&.

Comment: @cbamber85 How did you solve your problem?

Comment: @hostilefork Yes, the SSCCE is a good idea. I tried it and so far it seems that a plan, simple example really works fine. I'll obviously have to dig deeper into the message preparation iself. +1 for the hint.

Comment: @TadejMali I was lucky enough to have an externally imposed 1024 character limit, so I just dumped the output to a `char[1024]`.  Not very classy, but fine for my purposes.  However using a `std::string` or `std::wstring`, would be a much better idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to the question is "Yes, a QString can safely be a member in an exception."

The problems which I encountered were due to the fact that the object, acting as a source of data for the `fDescription`, had a bug. It implemented a getter method:

```
class Source
{
private: QString fData;
public:  QString GetData(void) { this->fData; }   // There is a missing return
}
```

Of course, the result of this call was the random value residing on the stack at the moment and hence the SIGSEGV.

The QString behaves as expected and with a valid reference to it, there are no problems using it in the exception.

The precise point where the SIGSEGV was raised was leaving the scope of the `try` block, where a copy of the exception is being constructed (remember: throw by value, catch by reference). The default copy constructor tries to create a shallow copy of all members and fails on accessing the invalid QString reference.

Comment: +1 for demonstrating the value of building a complete simple repro case...also note, you can mark your own answer as accepted to close the question!